# Excel formula for Sum of Power , Need to Expand Cell by Cell

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Thanks lot for all support...

I need to write one formula and Drag down to get the sum of the power 2.

=POWER(B2,2)+POWER(B3,2)+POWER(B4,2)+POWER(B5,2)

[image: Sum of Power]

I need to get the Sum of Power 2, For that need to write formula in cell C2 and Need to Drag till C5 .

Because I have more than 100 cell to drag this same Formula

Because if I type Manually it very critical to add one by one.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HpWP5fRC42JA1LvrCxnqsa7sIN64KfjlTkk-UjXvhhM/edit?usp=sharing

Best regard
Indika

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(B$2:B2^2)` and drag down

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT(which will work in Excel or Google-sheets):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B$2:B2^2)
```

[image]

And drag that down.

Or if you have Office 365 Excel you can put:

```
=SCAN(0,B2:B5,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b^2))
```

In C2 and it will spill.

[image]

Comment: [Nice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WAOxKOmR90) `SCAN` @Scott-Craner

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Column E for example:

```
for the first cell(E2) = POWER(B2,2)
for the second cell(E3) = POWER(B3,2)+E2
cell E4 = POWER(B4,2)+E3
```

and so on...